# GWT JSNI - JavaScriptException TypeError - method is not a function

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, jsni

I want to be able to call a method declared in my `StartView` class from the `onclick` event in Javascript. I am following the official GWT documentation, but am still getting a `JavaScriptException TypeError - doThing is not a function` error in the console. I have reviewed other similar questions here on SO and have not found a solution as of yet. I have attempted to implement a solution in JSNI and JSInterop - and what I have below is the furthest I have gotten past GWT compilation errors.

StartView.java - I call `StartView.loadJS()` when `StartView` is initialized

```
    public void doThing() {
        System.out.println("do thing");
    }

    public static native void loadJS() /*-{
        var that = this;
        $wnd.doThing = $entry(function() {
            that.@package.StartView::doThing()();
        });
    }-*/;
```

start.js (External js file, Injected into StartView via ScriptInjector. Other methods use  JSInterop)

```
...
// Inside of my onclick handler
 window.doThing();
```

When I click the element, I get the following error in the console:

```
Exception: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : that_0_g$.doThing_0_g$ is not a function
```

When I put `window.doThing` in the console, it does return the function - so it does appear to be loading the connector, but is having trouble finding the actual method to call. Curious what else I am missing. Would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, obligatory "Don't use JSNI for new code" - unless you project relies on an ancient GWT build, this is easier in JsInterop. First, define (or reuse) a `@JsFunction` interface that describes the contract for JS to call into Java, make a global field that you can assign this to, and then export your instance method in vanilla java:

```
/** Like Runnable, but no default methods, and has {@link JsFunction}. */
@JsFunction
public interface JsRunnable {
  void run(); // your example has no params and no return type, so this fits
}

public static void loadJS() {
  JsRunnable lambda = this::doThing; // bug is clear in java!

  // Assign as a new property on window
  Js.asPropertyMap(DomGlobal.window).set("doThing", lambda);
}

public void doThing() {
  System.out.println("do thing");
}
```

Note that the translation of loadJS makes it clear why your JSNI isn't working (more on that in a moment) - Java will complain if you try to use `this`, since `loadJS()` is static and has no `this`! But, you're calling `loadJS()` from inside the constructor, you could pass the instance as an argument, or make `loadJS()` non-static.

---

From your question

```java
    public static native void loadJS() /*-{
        var that = this; // Where should "this" come from?
        $wnd.doThing = $entry(function() {
            that.@package.StartView::doThing()();
        });
    }-*/;
```

As this is a `static` method, there is no `this` (okay, in JS there *is* a `this`, but it isn't the `StartView`, it is something else entirely). Since `doThing` is a non-`static` method, there is no clear way to say which `StartView` instance you want to have `doThing()` called on.

The simplest answer then is to remove `static` from that method, so that `this` is correctly captured, as you intended. Another choice could be to pass in a `StartView` instance to `loadJS` and call doThing on that instance.

The error you're getting is almost certainly that `this` turns out to be `window`, and the `@package.StartView::doThing()` reference represents some obfuscated method name that doesn't exist on window, which makes sense, since you intended `this` to be a `StartView` instance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. I did in fact end up using JSInterop to solve this.